# PGP - MIME, is it correct?

Tags: encryption, rsa, pgp

I see following x.509 certificate attached(or may be signed, not sure) with OpenPGP key. Is that s/MIME certificate attached with PGP? What that does? Can this be created with GnuPG or probably, how it can be created.

[image]

Comment: What makes you think anything there is signed with OpenPGP? All of the attributes you left visible are commonly/standardly used in (the Distinguished Names in) X.509 and thus S/MIME, while email addresses without any label saying EMAIL _and_ unstructured names are normally used in PGP. GnuPG certainly doesn't handle X.509 certs, and S/MIME software generally doesn't support OpenPGP (or GnuPG) keys or even messages.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 actually GnuPG ships with `gpgsm` which can do all sorts of operations related to S/MIME (and the windows version of GnuPG also has a GUI for S/MIME IIRC).